# Loading async JS then calling functions?

Tags: javascript, ajax, import

I'm looking for something similar to how Google Analytics JavaScript snippet works.

For example I have this,

```
(function(d, t) {
    var g = d.createElement(t),
        s = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
    g.src = 'myjs.js';
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(g, s);
}(document, 'script'));
```

The script defines a class but when I call this:

```
var newClass = new myclass('myparam');
```

I get a not defined error. However if I wait and call it again in the console I no longer get the error. I'm assuming the script hasn't yet fully loaded which is why the class doesn't exist.

However it's possible to call Google Analytics functions directly after import, for example,

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', '[userid]', '[website]');
```

How can I do this with my script?

Answer (score 2):

What that GA code does is create the object immediately with inline code. The object just stores up calls in an array until the GA script is loaded. The GA script then consumes the array. (See details below.)

You can't do that with the code you've shown, because A) It's a constructor function, and B) Your code uses the return value.

Here's the detail on what that GA code does:

```
(function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
    // Remember the name 'ga' on window, using the property GoogleAnalyticsObject
    i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;

    // Create or retrieve the 'ga' function. If there already is one,
    // it's used as-is. If not, create a new function.
    i[r] = i[r] || function () {
        // The bit in parens initializes an array if there isn't one
        // Then the push call remembers the arguments for this call
        (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
    }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); // The bit after the comma sets or updates the `l` property on the function with the timestamp of when this code was run.
    // From here fairly standard, load the GA script asynchronously
    a = s.createElement(o),
    m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
    a.async = 1;
    a.src = g;
    m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
})(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');
```